# flattening a fasta file

Tags: ruby, bioinformatics

I have a fasta file that is created by a ruby script that I have created; However,it has a number of duplicate sequences that are under different sequence ID's and I want to flatten the file such that I can get from a this ...

data in input fasta file (example.fa)

```
>isotig00009_f3.4.1 
ITLKPCGVPFSCCIPDQASGVANTQCGYGVRSPEQQNTFHTKIYTTGCADMFTMWINRYLYYIAGIAGVIVLVELFGFCFAHSLINDIKRQKARWAHR
>isotig00037_f3.1.1 
KLSLIVVNHSMVASKFERVILAYTSIIIEVSPAKRRRNGKILRKNTIRFRWQTFRILSAFTVVTFSKMMTQKI
>isotig00045_f1.15.3
YKINKRP
>isotig00046_f3.15.3
YKINKRP
>isotig00047_f3.15.3
YKINKRP
>isotig00048_f1.15.3
YKINKRP
>isotig00049_f1.15.3
YKINKRP
>isotig00050_f2.15.3
YKINKRP
>isotig00051_f1.15.3
YKINKRP
```

to this (in the output file - output.fa)...

```
>isotig00009_f3.4.1 
ITLKPCGVPFSCCIPDQASGVANTQCGYGVRSPEQQNTFHTKIYTTGCADMFTMWINRYLYYIAGIAGVIVLVELFGFCFAHSLINDIKRQKARWAHR
>isotig00037_f3.1.1 
KLSLIVVNHSMVASKFERVILAYTSIIIEVSPAKRRRNGKILRKNTIRFRWQTFRILSAFTVVTFSKMMTQKI
>isotig00045_f1.15.3 : isotig00046_f3.15.3 : isotig00047_f3.15.3 : isotig00048_f1.15.3 : isotig00049_f1.15.3 : isotig00050_f2.15.3 : isotig00051_f1.15.3
YKINKRP
```

I have made a small script that takes out one copy of the sequences but despite trying for quite some time, I seem to be unable to add any seq IDs for each of the sequences. One thing I tried that didn't work (see commented part below), was to try and extract the unique sequences and then pull out the sequence_IDs...

Here is the script I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

filename = "./example.fa"
text = File.read(filename)

def seq_uniq(input, output)
    parser = /^>.*\n(.*)/i
    seq_id_parser = /^(>.*)\n(.*)/i
    file = File.new("#{output}", "w")
    input.scan(parser).uniq.each do |seq|
        file.puts seq
#        input.scan(seq_id_parser) do |seq_id, seq_actual|
#           if seq_actual == seq
#               file.puts seq_id
#           end
#        end
    end
    file.close
end


seq_uniq(text, "./output.fa")
```

I would be highly grateful, if someone could point me in the right direction. Since this needs to be embedded into a large ruby script that produces a html webpage, I would be highly grateful if you only use ruby (or

EDIT:

To clarify, I want to flatten the fasta file to put all Seq. IDs that identify the same sequence on a single line (separated by a :) and then have the sequence on the next line.

Many thanks

Comment: The `ruby` tag is usually enough to scope answers to Ruby. I am not sure if the `dna` gem might help with your parsing - https://github.com/audy/dna ?

Comment: What are you trying to say with your sample output (from this... to this...)?  (e.g. You have multiple files with identical output but instead would like unique output per file?)  The colon separated syntax of your (presumable) filenames is confusing.

Comment: @maerics No, I am not dealing with filenames or a number of files - rather, the data I am dealing with is contained within a fasta file (example.fa). The typical fasta format is having a Sequence Identifier on 1 line and then the sequence on the next. I have also further clarified this in the main post. Here, I want  put all the Seq. Ids with the same seq. on 1 line (separated by a :) and then the seq. on the next.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I misunderstood the fasta file format as some commentary or example usage =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the fasta file and create a hash of "sequence => list of ids with same sequence" as you go.  Note that this solution assumes that the input file has only single ids per line, if there are multiple then you will need to improve the parser:

```ruby
def uniq_sequences(input)
  ids_by_sequence = {}
  input.split(/\n/).each_slice(2) do |id, sequence|
    id = id.gsub(/^>\s*/,'') # Remove the leading ">".
    ids_by_sequence[sequence] = [] unless ids_by_sequence[sequence]
    ids_by_sequence[sequence] << id # Store all ids with the same sequence.
  end
  # Return a string of aggregated ids per same sequence.
  ids_by_sequence.map do |sequence, ids|
    ">#{ids.join(' : ')}\n#{sequence}"
  end.join("\n")
end

puts uniq_sequences(File.read('./example.fa'))
```

On your sample input you should get the following output:

```
>isotig00009_f3.4.1 
ITLKPCGVPFSCCIPDQASGVANTQCGYGVRSPEQQNTFHTKIYTTGCADMFTMWINRYLYYIAGIAGVIVLVELFGFCFAHSLINDIKRQKARWAHR
>isotig00037_f3.1.1 
KLSLIVVNHSMVASKFERVILAYTSIIIEVSPAKRRRNGKILRKNTIRFRWQTFRILSAFTVVTFSKMMTQKI
>isotig00045_f1.15.3 : isotig00046_f3.15.3 : isotig00047_f3.15.3 : isotig00048_f1.15.3 : isotig00049_f1.15.3 : isotig00050_f2.15.3 : isotig00051_f1.15.3
YKINKRP
```